# How to measure if there is current between point A and B when source and grounding is unknown

Tags: current, grounding

I understand the headline makes little sense, so here is a clarification on what's going on.

**I used thick steel rods to create a second floor (loft) in my apartment. Those steel rods are attached via long steel bolts in the (concrete) floor and the walls. My computer is right next to one of those steel rods. When I touch my computer housing (which is connected in a grounded 3-pin socket) with one hand and the steel rod with the other I receive some rather high AC voltage (*even when the computer is off*) - it's high enough that my arm is still "muddy" after 3 days. I also used an amplifier connected to the same outlet to replicate the experiment.**

I am quite sure that the construction workers [when doing that steel-second-floor] hit a powerline, "closing a circuit" when I touch something grounded (the PC) and the steel rod at the same time.

In order to solve the problem I have to identify which circuit breaker is responsible for the powerline which is sending current to the steel-construction, so I can replace it. I'd rather not use my body as a "sensor" anymore - what other options do I have? I tried using a multimeter but to no avail(1).

Of course I had an electrician coming in today, but he was unfortunately clueless and just said to avoid touching electronics and the steel construction at the same time, but I believe living like that could pose potential bigger hazards.

Your support will be highly appreciated - I am a foreigner living in China, we got 230V here and as much as I like Chinese roast chicken I don't like to turn into one.

PS: I know the difference between static electricity, a 12V DC running through my body and AC hitting you - this is definitely AC on the rather stronger side as the side effects after two shocks are still present after 3 days.

(1) Setting the multimeter to AC voltage, connecting one end to the steel rod and the other to the computer housing shows 0 voltage.

Comment: If the situation is as you suspect then it should be easy to show an ac voltage between the iron rod and ground using a common multimeter. Explain in detail what you mean by "to no avail".

Comment: Exactly, you need to provide unambiguous information i.e. you need to make a proper measurement.

Comment: I set the multimeter to AC voltage (750) and connected one end to the steel rod, the other to the PC housing however it showed 0.00 - I repeated the test with other multimeter settings as well in case my theory was wrong. I cannot get the multimeter to show anything, yet when using my body well... I am not an expert at all in electricity, it's possible i use the multimeter in a wrong way or my whole theory is flawed

Comment: What do you see when you measure between iron rod and ground, and between PC housing and ground?

Comment: @ocrdu what you mean is, I should connect one end of the multimeter to the socket (ground) and the other to the pc housing right, setting at AC. And repeat with one end at steel rod and one end in power-outlet ground? Just clarifying, because when I tried to measure the voltage in the socket the circuit breaker went off.

Comment: That is what I mean, yes, if you are sure the socket has been properly connected and sure about which pin is ground. Did the fuse/circuit braker go, or the Earth leakage circuit breaker, if any? Did you measure the socket with the multimeter set to AC voltage (750V) when it went? Between which pins did you measure?

Comment: @ocrdu thanks for your help ---- this is the socket in question ( https://i0.wp.com/welcometochina.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Chinese.jpg ) - i used the bottom one to connect a pc cord, then connected the multimeter (one to the left, the other to the right) - i suppose the circuit breaker kicked in because it was missing ground. DMM was at 750 @ AC . Unfortunately the "electrician" that came today didn't even want to do that test -

Comment: Are you sure the steel beams are electrified, not the socket ground? Sometimes *really bad* electricians do electrify the socket ground.

Comment: Or leave it unconnected.

Comment: @user253751thats the problem - I don't know for sure. I can touch the beams without issues at all, as long as the other hand doesn't touch anything else connected to a power line. I cannot say for sure if the beams act as ground, neutral or live. If it helps - my right hand was touching the computer, my left hand the steel beam - my left hand has 'issues' now. Maybe thats a clue. This whole thing is driving me crazy.

Comment: @ocrdu i will follow up on your test instructions tomorrow and report back the results. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The vertical one in the middle should be ground; you can use that one for the measurements. Be careful with what you touch when measuring and stay alive. I don't understand how measuring voltage between live and 0, not touching ground, would pop a fuse, BTW. Measuring voltage between live and ground could trigger an Earth leakage circuit breaker, though.

Comment: ... unless you have the meter incorrectly set up to measure amps instead of volts.

Comment: how far is your apartment from actual ground (dirt)?

Answer (score 0):

One guess:

There's no connection from your steel frame to the mains AC line, it's connected only to the ground through the concrete which generally tend to be more or less conductive.

But your computer isn't grounded. Modern switchmode power supplies unfortunately have capacitors between the mains AC lines and the metal case of the computer which in addition is connected to the low voltage side GND inside the computer. The capacitors are needed to reduce radio frequency emissions as well to the air and to the mains AC network.

The capacitive mains AC leak onto your hands would be shorted if there were proper grounding. But  without grounding the current through you can really be painful although not as high as something which is considered lethal.

The problem is common, it's presented here in EESE several times and I have seen sometimes it's self-caused when people

- break groundings which collect noise their audio systems or
- use non-grounded outlets with equipment (like many computers) which are designed to have properly grounded mains AC input.

A competent electrician would check and fix the grounding but that needs real experience, brave soul is not enough to stay alive.

A multimeter in AC voltage range should show if there's a voltage between your computer case and the built steel frame. That's assuming you can use the multimeter and it's not broken. Your "tripped the breaker -incident" hints that your knowledge needs some fixes. Measuring against known ground, other than the unknown would be usefull, but also dangerous for an unexperienced person. Get help!

As said, that was a guess. The other possibility is that there's a live mains AC voltage in your steel frame. Or there were until you tripped the safety breaker somewhere. The voltage returns when the owner of the breaker resets it.

Get an electrician which understands the case, believes you and is free of any general local reasons to stay blind in front of wrong wirings and building errors.