How to do calculations in a DC circuit when connected to a ground
Let's say you have a simple circuit such as the one given in the image below. I am a bit confused about the way the ground works in this example. The point A is connected to the battery's positive terminal with a potential of by example $$V_+ = 5V$$ so that $$V_- = 0V$$ But at the same time point A is connected to the ground at zero Volts. My question is: what is the potential in point A in the image, is it zero volts or 5 volts? I think I am not really understanding what a ground does/is and that this causes the problem.


Assume ground takes all presence. Then apply your voltage sources and check your voltage levels compared to ground. What do you get?

Maybe this will answer your question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/545322/professor-said-no-current-flows-to-ground/545334#545334


what is the potential in point A in the image, is it zero volts or 5 volts?

It is \$0\$ volts. Ground is by definition \$0\$ volts, and point A is directly connected to ground by a schematic wire, so it has the same voltage.
The battery does not define any absolute potential, it defines a difference in the potential between two points. You should be able to calculate the potential at the "top" of the battery from that.

That makes sense, I do still have one question though. If you have a galvanic cell, you calculate the potentials of each terminal separately to then find the voltage by subtracting them, are these separate calculations then also not absolute?

@MichVaughan In electronics generally, we don't deal with absolute potentials, but only with potential differences. However, we can arbitrarily choose some point and call it ground. We can then speak of the potential difference between a point and ground as the potential referenced to ground. To save time, we often omit the phrase "referenced to ground", and if we are not speaking about a potential difference or voltage between two specific nodes, but the potential or voltage of single specific node, then one should assume it is the potential or voltage referenced to ground. Make sense?



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Ground on a circuit is just a point of reference for voltage measurements in the circuit. (It may also be connected to Earth.)
In much the same way as a surveyor needs a reference point from which all heights are measured, for electrical circuits it is convenient to do the same thing for voltage measurements. A surveyor may pick a point on the ground or may use sea-level as the reference. All readings after that will have a positive value if their elevation is greater than the reference and will have a negative value if their elevation is lower than the reference.
Most electronic battery circuits consider the battery negative as the ground as shown in Figure 1a. Note the voltmeter reading is showing +5 V.
Your circuit has the battery inverted. Since there is five volts between the battery terminals and you have the positive grounded it means that R2 has -5 V across it as shown by VM2.
Note that as a result of your battery inversion current flows the opposite direction.

The term "Ground" is much abused in electronics.  In some cases (such as AC power wiring and some radio antenna systems) "Ground" really does mean "a connection to the Earth", but more often the Ground symbol is simply used to mark the point in a circuit that we want to consider as "Zero volts" and use as a reference when measuring voltage elsewhere in the circuit. It might be better to call this "Ground" "Common" or "Reference", but this misuse of the term "Ground" is so deeply embedded that we are stuck with it.
This Reference/Common Ground is often the most negative point in the circuit, but could be elsewhere.  In many analog circuits, where we have both positive and negative voltages, "Ground" will be the mid-point of the power supply.  There was one logic family (ECL) which officially ran from a -5.2 volt supply - in that case, "Ground" was the positive terminal of the power supply.
When building battery-powered circuits on a plastic breadboard we will still refer to the zero volt point as "Ground".

Your picture has 2 nodes, marked in my picture with the \$\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}\$ and \$\color{green}{\mathrm{green}}\$ colors. Your point A belongs to the \$\color{green}{\mathrm{green}}\$ node.

The term “voltage at the point (node)” implicitly means “voltage between this point and another point”.
That “another” (a reference) point is an arbitrary-selected point, which we will name “the ground” and then — to emphasize that we selected this particular point — we usually mark it with one of the “ground symbols” (e.g. as that in the bottom of your picture, or in the bottom of my one).
              You selected the point A as your reference point (i.e. as the ground).
So,

the voltage at the point A in your picture will be the voltage between the point A and the point A itself, which is, of course, 0 V,

the voltage at the positive (+) terminal of your 5 V battery is the same, 0 V, because it is in the same (\$\color{green}{\mathrm{green}}\$) node as the point A),

the voltage at the negative (–) terminal of your 5 V battery is 5 V less than in its positive terminal, i.e. -5 V.
(The “+” and “–” marks in your battery terminals means nothing more than the “+” terminal has a higher potential than the “–” terminal.)


